# Is the pagination in Spring Boot restricted for the table content only?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I am currently working on an online exam project.The development of this project involve the below mentioned language and framework **spring boot, hibernate, mysql, thymeleaf and bootstrap**. However, I have some doubt on the pagination of the webpage content. Is the pagination in the spring boot only restricted for the table content only?

It is because I need to  separate each single question to be displayed in different page. Each question will only display one question. What should I do if the pagination is not workable for the content in the table format? If have, is there any resources and documentation that I can follow to do so?

Comment: I'm not sure, I4d guess it's not `table restricted`.  You might try :
`@Repository
public interface MyRepo {
  @Query(value = "Select ... From ... Where ...", countRequest = "Select count(...) From ... Where ...")
  Page<SomeEntity> specialSelect(Pageable pageable); 
}`

Comment: Can you confirm, do you mean displaying the data in a table UI or a DB table of data?

Comment: If it is the latter, you can simply limit the result of each page to one result per page, then each page would then be one question.